# Can't delete files on sparse bundle apfs volume ("rm failed - no space left on device")

Tags: backup, disk-utility, apfs, sparsebundle

I have a sparse bundle with an apfs volume on it. I recently filled it up with an `rsync` operation. Since then I cannot delete files anymore; the `rm` complains that the disk is full. The same happens if I use `echo > file.txt` for an existing file; or `truncate -s 0 file.txt`.

Nothing is using the volume since it was a dedicated backup storage - nothing except my (manually executed) `rsync` and my manual shell commands touched it.

It seems like the file system cannot find a few spare bits to modify its internal structure.

I unmounted it (without problems/errors/warnings), and now it does not mount anymore (it says "Keine aktivierbaren Dateisysteme" - probably "no file systems can be activated" or something like that).

The underlying file system is error free and was not disconnected/unmounted during the whole procedure.

Two questions:

- Is there a sane way to fix the original problem (file system full + no way to remove files)?
- Is this a known problem? At the end of this day, this means total file system loss simply due to it being full. Seems hardly believable to me. Or is a apfs volume on a sparse bundle considered experimental?

This is on Mojave (10.14.6). The file system which contains the sparse bundle is a smb:// share (which itself has plenty of space left).

EDIT: It turns out I have this issue https://matt.sh/apfs-object-map-free-recovery, i.e. a broken and unrecoverable (at least with MacOS standard tools) volume. If someone else arrives here through this search, that link may help for *that* issue (it also has tips on recovering with some open source tool, which I didn't test). I'm still curious about whether anyone else had the "can't delete - no space left" issue; but maybe it is just a convoluted error message caused by the broken FS. Which is a topic for another question.

Comment: Have you emptied the **Trash**? Have you tried to free up space by moving a _file_ off of the _sparse bundle_ via **Finder** by dragging it to another _volume_ while holding **⌘** down? Have you, via **Terminal**, examined `/Volumes/$NAME/.Trashes/..` to see if it contains any files that have not been deleted? E.g. `sudo du -h /Volumes/$NAME/.Trashes` while substituting `$NAME` for the actual volume name ( or `ls -alR` for `du -h`). You might also try _compacting_ the _sparse bundle_, however I'd probably want to have a backup of it and do it from the system hosting it if it's hosted on a Mac.